# Can I use script to move items to a named layer in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-scripting

I have a programmable keyboard that I am using to assign shortcuts and nmacros to for various programs. One of the things I want to do is move selected objects to a named layer.

I always have four layers consistent throughout most of my documents

```
Background
Artwork
Notes
Guides
```

I have scripts that select one of these layers when I want to work on them and I've applied a shortcut to it through an action.

```
var aDoc = app.activeDocument;
aDoc.activeLayer = aDoc.layers.getByName("Artwork");
```

Sometimes while working I forget to change layers and on big projects, this can be problematic and I need a quick way to move the selected objects to a named layer by pressing one key.

I'm sure this can be done with a script but I do not know anything about Javascript, I have read the documentation, but I cannot understand it.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Objects have a method xalled move that moves them.in hierarchy. While the function to move in cancas space is called translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the selected objects to a layer named "Target" using this script:

```
var docSelected = app.activeDocument.selection;  
var targetLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["Target"];

for (s = 0; s < docSelected.length; s++) {  
     myPath = docSelected[s];
     myPath.move(targetLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
}
```

You just have to modify the "Target" name in the second line. Create four scripts each with the four layer names and assign a different shortcut for each one.